# Jenkins job was poked by a GitHub webhook but didn't start

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am running GHE 2.3.1 in private mode (anonymous cloning and repo browsing is not allowed in my organization) and we use Jenkins for CI.  Before I put GHE into private mode I could have Jenkins fire jobs for repos when push events happen, using webhooks.  After I set private mode this no longer happens.

In Jenkins I see that the webhook was received but the job didn't start.

```
Sep 23, 2015 4:13:35 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
Received POST for http://github.company.com/org/repo
Sep 23, 2015 4:13:35 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1 run
Poked Job Name - build master
```

My job has no history of starting and failing.  This is true for all jobs relying on push hooks.  However, my jobs that run on pull request hooks are working, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with all latest plugins and there is no git version issue as well. However, the issue gets disappeared once we run manual build or if we restart jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was an error in the GitHub Hook log that pointed me to the version of Git installed on the Jenkins master server.  After updating it to the newest version the error went away and jobs started to build on hooks again.

Comment: would you mind sharing more details on this? it'd be nice to document the answer and see if it can help others. What error were you getting in the GitHub Hook log?

Comment: I would be happy to share more information but this was so long ago that I don't remember.  I've also changed employers and no longer have access to that Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating the Github plugin from v1.11.3 to v1.14.0, and the GitHub API Plugin to v1.69

Answer (score 0):

Add this trigger block in your Jenkinsfile then run your job once manually.

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
       githubPush()
    }
}
```